# Mvc4 - deployed application works fine on chrome but blank page on IE 9?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I deployed my intranet mvc4 application on the web server. It works fine on google chrome, but on IE9the app appears for a second and then all i see is a blank page. However, if iuse 'F12 tools', I can see that all the data are there. I've used MVC4, Jquery UI, Bootstrap from Twitter in my app. Any help would be greatly appreciated ? Thanks

Comment: If you click the profiler tab in the developer tools and start profiling, do you see any errors when you reload the site?

Comment: Sorted..!!..Thanks a lot. my ie was running in compatible view. I changed it to IE 8, and it worked.!!..Is it possible to permanently switch it to IE 8 view by default ? Do I have to do this on all the machines that would be accessing this application ?

Answer (score 4):

For some completely unknown reason (to me..) Microsoft has decided that IE7 is the de-facto standard for Intranet sites.

IE8, IE9 and IE10 all fall back to compatibility mode (IE7 mode) when it detects/thinks a site is on an **intranet**.

You can fix this by telling your website (the server) to tell your browser which mode to use.  Do this by adding the following to the  section of your _layout.cshtml:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

IE=9 / IE=8 force a specific version, IE=Edge forces the latest IE (ie the version of the browser you have).  In my case I've used IE9 as I've developed against IE9 and tested against IE9, any minor changes in IE10 won't break the site as IE10 will open in IE9 mode.

Edit: There's a *lot* more info here: [stackoverflow/6771258](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge)